# Unable to complete sudo apt-get update

Tags: updates

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS (Precise Pangolin). I tried to run `sudo apt-get update` on shell and it ends up with following errors after couple of seconds:

```
Err http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
Could not connect to pk.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (58.65.218.244), connection timed out

W: Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/Release.gpg Unable to connect to pk.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: disable proxy by changing proxy method to none.

Comment: @avinash-raj Please use the code tag to highlight any code. Thanks

Comment: goto setting click network and down there is Network proxy click it and make it none and apply system wide

Comment: I did do the same as suggested and then restart my machine and now I am getting following error if try to run `sudo apt-get update`       `E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/`

Comment: I did manage to run `sudo apt-get update`, but still same errors as I originally posted

Comment: check here: http://askubuntu.com/a/102084/256029

Comment: Thanks kamil, I have fixed that locking thing now I am back to original problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Open **/etc/apt/sources.list** and replace **pk.archive.ubuntu.com** with **archive.ubuntu.com**, after that save the file and run **sudo apt-get update**

Comment: Many Thanks, Problem Solved For me..You are the boss.